# How can I daily backup SVN Repos to another PC?

Tags: svn, backup

I have all my projects on SVN Server which is a PC with 2 TB  harddisk and 8 GB RAM.Now this pc is not reliable so I want to use this pc as svn server but also for my safe side I want to back up this SVN server repos daily backup to another PC

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`svnadmin hotcopy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.hotcopy.html) command to backup to a remote network share. If you use VisualSVN Server, try the [Backup and Restore](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/backup/) feature. You can schedule the backups or make one-time backups using the **Backup Repository** wizard in VisualSVN Server Manager console or [**Backup-SvnRepository**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/) PowerShell cmdlet.